# F# Fabulous Xamarin: update view from code without user input

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#, fabulous

I'm new to Elmish.Xamarin and Xamarin itself. I'm trying to build an application, using [this calculator example](https://github.com/fsprojects/Fabulous/blob/master/Samples/CounterApp/CounterApp/CounterApp.fs). Main difference is that in this example UI is updated upon user input, and `update` function is pure and just evaluates next state of model:

```
let update msg model =
    match msg with
    | Clear -> Initial
    | Digit digit ->
        match model with
        | Initial | Error | Result _ -> Operand (double digit)
        | Operand op -> Operand (double (string op + string digit))
        | OperandOperator (operand, operator) -> OperandOperatorOperand (operand, operator, double digit)
        | OperandOperatorOperand (op1, operator, op2) -> OperandOperatorOperand (op1, operator, double (string op2 + string digit))
    | Operator operator ->
        match model with
        | Initial | Error -> model
        | Result operand // previously calculated result is now the first operand
        | Operand operand | OperandOperator (operand, _) -> OperandOperator(operand, operator) 
        | OperandOperatorOperand _ -> calculate model msg
        | Equals -> calculate model msg
```

I need a different scenario: user's input **doesn't affect UI directly**, instead I store user's messages and evaluate next state **on schedule**, so in my app's core I pass `updateUI: gameState -> unit` func:

```
let gameAgentFn (mailboxNetwork: MailboxNetwork) updateUi gameState cmd =
    let timerAgent = timerAgent mailboxNetwork
    match gameState.gameFrame with
    | Frame field ->
        let gameState = Game.updateGameState gameState cmd
        timerAgent.Post Next
        updateUi gameState
        gameState
```

Problem is I can't understand, what function to pass and how to build interaction with this design, since as far as I can see, it expects me to pass pure function to evaluate next state and the rest is being done underneath.

Comment: Don't use `Program.mkSimple`, use `mkProgram` instead. It will take the `update` function that allows side-effects.